# Java Apache Commons Compress 7zip, corrupt file error

Tags: java, 7zip, lzma

7 zip files (lzma) format, want to compress and encrypt.
I want to use Apache Commons Compress.
I am using this function, however, the decompressed files are corrupted.

Thanks

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    SevenZOutputFile sevenZOutput = new SevenZOutputFile(new File("outFile.7z"));
    File entryFile = new File("D:/image.jpg");
    SevenZArchiveEntry entry = sevenZOutput.createArchiveEntry(entryFile, entryFile.getName());

    byte fileContent[] = new byte[(int)entryFile.length()];

    sevenZOutput.putArchiveEntry(entry);
    sevenZOutput.write(fileContent);
    sevenZOutput.closeArchiveEntry();
    sevenZOutput.close();         
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the error you receive?

Comment: "outfile.7z-> image.jpg" When I open the file 
"This image file is damaged" I'm getting warnings. ok ?

Comment: What warnings are you getting? It's difficult to answer your question without all of the details.

Comment: outfile.7z the contents of the archive, image.jpg file does not open. http://www.sendspace.com/file/42twrn

Comment: I figured, okay, thank you. How do I add a password to the archive so?

Answer (score 0):

I figured, okay, thank you. How do I encryption the archive?

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
SevenZOutputFile sevenZOutput = new SevenZOutputFile(new File("outFile.7z"));
File entryFile = new File("D:/image.jpg");
SevenZArchiveEntry entry = sevenZOutput.createArchiveEntry(entryFile, entryFile.getName());
sevenZOutput.putArchiveEntry(entry);

FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(entryFile);
                int len;
                byte buffer[] = new byte[8192];
                int transferedMegaBytes2=0;
                while ((len = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    sevenZOutput.write(buffer, 0, len);                    
                    transferredBytes += len;
                    int transferedMegaBytes = (int) (transferredBytes / 1048576);                          
                    if(transferedMegaBytes>transferedMegaBytes2){
                    System.out.println("Transferred: " + transferedMegaBytes + " Megabytes.");
                    transferedMegaBytes2=transferedMegaBytes;
                    }
                }
sevenZOutput.closeArchiveEntry();
sevenZOutput.close();    
}
```

Comment: If you happy with your solution you can accept your answer